# What is the difference between node vs nodejs command in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, installation

I have untarred node.js from the tar file given on nodejs.org, but when i try executing my js program through node command nothing happens, but on the other hand nodejs command runs executes the file.

So my question is what's the  **difference between node command and nodejs command** as and will it effect my programs as i **didn't build from the source code.** And i of that is the reason of this discrepancy.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: xubuntu 13.10 (Debian based Linux OS)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is highly dependent on many factors.  Mainly, it depends on what `node` and `nodejs` in your shell actually are.  You can check this using `type node` / `type nodejs` and/or `which node` / `which nodejs` (or perhaps `whereis`).  This *also* depends on the OS and the shell.

My guess is that `which -a node` will yield `/usr/sbin/node` which is *not* the nodejs executable and thus why it does not execute your node code.  On my system, it is:

```
/usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node -> /usr/bin/nodejs
```

i.e. `node` is just a symbolic link to `nodejs`, which is the executable.

You can also create this alias yourself so that it overrides whatever `node` is for you.

Answer (score 15):

Some of these answers were difficult to understand for me, so I'm going to write the answer that would've helped me.

`node` is something like a radio telemetry solving program, they just happened to snag the name `node` first. `nodejs` is what you're after. So 
make sure you:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

then, to fix the lame naming issue, create a symlink. A symbolic link between `node` and `nodejs`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

The first part is the original file placement, and then where it should link to. 
You could also create an alias in your bash profile, which is also pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

For sure available 'node' package is not related to nodejs.

Just take a look at this node from here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

> There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from node to nodejs. You'll need to symlink /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs or you could uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node Program to avoid that conflict.

So it seems like you may purge that radio program with

```
dpkg --purge node
```

And then install nodejs via one of common ways f.e. from precompiled deb packages available like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

*But nodejs updates faster than packages so after you will get any nodejs version available it's more efficient to use this module for managing nodejs versions - https://github.com/visionmedia/n*

At least after some tests this solution looks most suitable for me at mac os.