# Node command isn't doing anything

Tags: node.js, linode

On my linode server that I have SSH'd into, when I type

```
$ node server.js
$
```

Nothing happens!

Even if the only contents of sever.js is util.log("HELLO");

Nothing is printed! Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `nodejs server.js`, just to make sure it's calling the right `node` program.

Comment: May be you would like see more about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457834/what-is-the-difference-between-node-vs-nodejs-command-in-terminal ,

node is simply a symbolic link to nodejs. So possibly in your case this symbolic link was not setup,hence not resulting in execution of nodejs