# Express 4 app - node ./bin/www X nodejs ./bin/www

Tags: node.js, heroku, express-4

I'm learning to work with node and express, I used express generator to setup a basic project and I pushed it to heroku, but I got this error in logs:

```
2015-12-27T16:29:01.478244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-12-27T16:29:03.533736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T16:29:03.522320+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T16:29:03.522335+00:00 app[web.1]: > application-name@0.0.1 start /app
2015-12-27T16:29:03.522337+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodejs ./bin/www
2015-12-27T16:29:03.522337+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T16:29:03.526805+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodejs: not found
2015-12-27T16:29:03.537910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
2015-12-27T16:29:03.538285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-12-27T16:29:03.538482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v0.12.7
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540547+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540546+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `nodejs ./bin/www`
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540547+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540548+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script 'nodejs ./bin/www'.
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540550+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540551+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     nodejs ./bin/www
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540552+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540714+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
2015-12-27T16:29:03.540922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-12-27T16:29:03.543464+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-27T16:29:03.543727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-12-27T16:29:03.543869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-12-27T16:29:04.374697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-12-27T16:29:04.392014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It started working when I changed this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodejs ./bin/www"
  },
```

to this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

but I don't know why, can anyone explain the difference between node and nodejs, and how this works with heroku.

Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457834/what-is-the-difference-between-node-vs-nodejs-command-in-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express generator creates a startup script that runs the command `node ./bin/www` which starts up your Express app by running the `.bin/www` JavaScript file. The problem was that there is/was no command labled `nodejs`, but there is one called `node` (which points to the node.js executable).

Nodejs (node.js) is often called just `node` for short, typically so for command prompts.